# Is DbContext safe to use after a database error occured

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What happens to Entity Frameworks DbContext and the entities regisered after an error occurs during SaveChanges() (for example an index prohibits duplicate rows or a timeout). Are they still usable or are they in an Inconsistant state and should be thrown away?

Comment: see this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are still usable provided you fix the original error. If it's a timeout, you can try again but if it's something like an index error then the issue would need resolving as calling `SaveChanges` will start a new transaction and try to save any changes you've made. If one change fails, the whole transaction is rolled back.

The chances of re-using a context without getting a new one though would depend on your architecture.

For instance, if you did something like:

```
using (var context = GetContext())
{
    //do something that goes wrong
}
```

I would expect appropriate error handling to be in place so that the context is closed (as it would be when hitting the end of the `using`) and and error shown so that context shouldn't be available anyway.

**Edit**

With regards to the comments, having a single context open for a long period of time isn't advisable. SQL server does it's own connection pooling which controls opening and closing connections so it's not slow to just open a context as and when you need it. This allows better control of the errors as well.

Comment: It is a Desktop App and we use one context per Window so the context is living quite long

Comment: Based on the research I've done on the matter, having one context open for a long period is a bad model. You should only have a context open as long as you need it.